# How are 2D Multidimensional arrays populated?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      double [][] DailyTemperature;

        double totalTracker = 0.0;
        String [] daysofweek = { "Monday ","Tuesday ","Wednsday ","Thursday","Friday ","Saturday ","Sunday "};

        DailyTemperature = new double[4][7];

        for ( int i = 0; i < DailyTemperature.length; i++ )
           for ( int j = 0; j < DailyTemperature[0].length; j++ )
            {
                System.out.print( "Enter " + daysofweek[j]+ "Temperature for week" + ( i + 1 ) + "\t");
                DailyTemperature[i][j] = scan.nextDouble( );

            }
```

So this question is just confirm how 2D arrays are populated, my question was inside the nested for loop as i increases to 1 does it stay as 1 until j is counted 7 times and then increment by 1, or do they simultaneously increment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it stay as 1 until j is counted 7 times and then increment by 1

Yes, but more precisely it starts with 0 so it stays as 0 and then increment by 1.

In fact you can verify this very easily by putting this println statement right before you prompt for input:

```
                System.out.println("i is now " + i + ", and j is now " + j);
```

And the output:

```
i is now 0, and j is now 0
Enter Monday Temperature for week1  100

i is now 0, and j is now 1
Enter Tuesday Temperature for week1 200

i is now 0, and j is now 2
Enter Wednsday Temperature for week1    300

.
.
.


i is now 0, and j is now 6
Enter Sunday Temperature for week1  700

i is now 1, and j is now 0
Enter Monday Temperature for week2  800

i is now 1, and j is now 1
Enter Tuesday Temperature for week2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just consider them as a stack. Starting from the outer loop you put it stack for execution then go inside so the loop which is at the deepest level will be at the top. You have to complete the work of topmost element or the deepest level loop then it goes to loop under it. This is just an analogy for this case.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop that is j continues to run exactly number of times until it reach to satisfy 'j < DailyTemperature[0].length' and then the other loop continues it's further iteration.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < DailyTemperature.length; i++ )//executes firstly once
           for ( int j = 0; j < DailyTemperature[0].length; j++ )// continues execution until j < DailyTemperature[0].length.
            {
                System.out.print( "Enter " + daysofweek[j]+ "Temperature for week" + ( i + 1 ) + "\t");
                DailyTemperature[i][j] = scan.nextDouble( );

            }
```